# Ruby regex help to replace substring

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to replace `field_to_replace` from

```
...<div>\r\n<span field=\"field_to_replace\">\r\n<div>....
```

There are multiple occurrences of `field_to_replace` in the string. I need to replace only this occurrence using the tag before and after it.

Comment: Oh my, this question again. OK, don't use a regular expression for this as it'll be extremely fragile and likely to break, especially if you don't own the HTML generator. The only time to consider it is for _EXTREMELY_ simple HTML/XML. Instead, [use a parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). The most commonly used one for Ruby is [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org). There are lots of examples on the internet and Stack Overflow explaining how to do this.

Comment: Okay, Thanks @theTinMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions to try to search or replace inside HTML or XML unless you are guaranteed that the source layout won't change. It's really easy to use a parser to make the changes, and they'll easily handle changes to the source.

This would replace all occurrences of the string in the HTML:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<div><span field='field_to_replace'><div>")
doc.to_html # => "<div><span field=\"field_to_replace\"><div></div></span></div>"

doc.search('div span[@field]').each do |span|
  span['field'] = 'foo'
end
doc.to_html # => "<div><span field=\"foo\"><div></div></span></div>"
```

If you want to replace just the first occurrence, use `at` instead of `search`:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<div><span field=\"field_to_replace\"><div><span field='field_to_replace'></span></div></span></div>")
doc.to_html # => "<div><span field=\"field_to_replace\"><div><span field=\"field_to_replace\"></span></div></span></div>"

doc.at('div span[@field]')['field'] = 'foo'
doc.to_html # => "<div><span field=\"foo\"><div><span field=\"field_to_replace\"></span></div></span></div>"
```

By defining the CSS selector you can identify the node quickly and easily. And, if you need even more power then XPath can be used instead of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be:

```
str = "...<div>\r\n<span field=\"field_to_replace\">\r\n<span field=\"field_to_replace\">\r\n<div>...."
str.split("field_to_replace").join("new_field")
```

Let us know if you need something more complex.

Comment: Agreed, str.gsub('field_to_replace', 'new_field'). Was trying to use methods more likely to be known, but your solution is better.